# XSLT: last element at any depth of all but specific type

Tags: xml, xslt

Using XSLT 1 I would like to select from an XML document the last node, at any depth, that is directly contained by a specific type but is not itself that type.

For example:

```
<root>
<div>
    <p>A node</p>
</div>
<div>
    <p>Another node</p>
    <div>
        <p>A third node</p>
        <div>
            <p>A fourth node</p>
            <p>The node <span>sub-element</span> that I want</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</root>
```

I would like to get <p>The node <span>sub-element</span> that I want</p> under this condition (re-writing the question for this specific case):

Selecting the last node, at any depth, directly contained by a div, but is not itself a div.

The answer should be abstractable to any depth (ie not "/div/div/div/p")

The <span> node should not be selected because its parent is not a div

Would be grateful for any help on this!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to get what you want using

```
(//div/*[not(self::div)])[last()]
```

The `//div/*[not(self::div)]` gives you all elements anywhere in the document that are the direct child of a `div` and are not themselves a `div`, and `[last()]` picks the last of these in document order.  Since children are considered to be after their parents in document order you can be sure that the selected element will not have any `div` descendants that themselves have children.

The parentheses are important, if you omit them then you get a very different expression

```
//div/*[not(self::div)][last()]
```

which will give you a sequence containing the last non-`div` element child of every `div` in the document at all levels (i.e. the `[last()]` applies to just the final step in the path rather than to the path as a whole).

---

Trivial XSLT example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select="(//div/*[not(self::div)])[last()]" />
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<p>The node <span>sub-element</span> that I want</p>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this; that's absolutely wonderful and extremely helpful!